# Canonicalized Mapping e WeakReference

Tags: java, desempenho, gerenciamento-de-memória, hashmap, garbage-collector

Gostaria que alguém pudesse explicar o conceito(e aplicações) de **Canonicalizing Mapping**  e como funcionaria a sua implementação de referencia usando **WeakHashMap**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Olá @Reginaldo Soares,

Para entender corretamente o funcionamento de um Canonicalized Mapping, vamos primeiro entender a acão do Garbage Collector e os tipos de referência que existem em Java.

**Em Java não liberamos memória programaticamente**

Como já é sabido pelos programadores, Java é uma linguagem em que não se faz necessário a alocação e desalocação de memória, como o é em C++. Dentro da Java Virtual Machine o Agente conhecido como Garbage Collector libera memória dos objetos que não tem mais referência, em outras palavras todo objeto criado, em geral tem uma referência para ele uma vez que o escopo dessa referência termine, ou que ela seja anulada - `variable = null` - o objeto em questão já pode ser coletado pelo Garbage Collector.

**Outros tipos de referência**

O comportamento descrito acima é o da maioria das aplicações que rodam na JVM. A este tipo de referência damos o nome de ***Strong Reference***. Objetos que tem String References ou referências fortes, só podem ser coletados uma vez que não exista mais nenhuma referência forte para eles, em um evento onde a JVM fica sem memória disponível para criação de novos objetos, e Error OutOfMemoryError java heap space é lançado, uma vez que a JVM não pode liberar os objetos com este tipo de referência.

**java.lang.ref - SoftReference, WeakReference e PhantomReference**

No pacote java.lang encontramos outros tipos de referência que podem ser usados para interação com o Garbage Collector, vamos analisar cada uma delas

**SoftReference**

Este tipo referência terá outra interação dentro da aplicação, o objeto para qual apenas houver referências dete tipo - referências leves - será coletado logo antes de um **OutOfMemoryError  heap space** ser lançado. Implementações da Java Virtual Machine que seguema risca as especificações devem coletar os objetos que tenham apenas SoftReferences antes de ficar sem memória.

Analisemos um exemplo - No código abaixo, estamos criando um ArrayList para armazenar objetos do tipo BigDecimal, interando e adicionando a cada loop o próximo número, indo de 0 a 10 milhões. Na minha máquina após iteracão de número *17864218* A Excessão *NullPointerException* é lancada.

```
import java.lang.ref.SoftReference;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;



public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Declaracao de uma SoftReference - note como ela funciona como um Wrapper
        SoftReference<List<BigDecimal>> listString = new SoftReference<>(new ArrayList<>(100000));
        for(int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++){
            System.out.println(i); 
            // o método get retorna o objeto ArrayList
            // após a iteracao de numero 17864218 este método retornou null, pois o objeto foi coletado
            listString.get().add(new BigDecimal(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Resultado:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.greentea.Main.main(Main.java:15)
```

(troque para uma referência normal, Strong Reference, e verá *OutOfMemoryError*)

**WeakReference**

WeakRererences diferentemente de SoftReferences, são fracas, uma vez que não exista nenhuma outra referência para qualquer objeto que tenha apenas WeakRerefences, Soft ou Strong, este objeto deve ser coletado no próximo ciclo do Garbage Collector.

Vejamos um exemplo

No código abaixo estamos criando uma nova instancia de um Object, assinalando ela a uma WeakReference a uma StrongReference, chamamos o Garbage Collector, observamos entao que a WeakReference ainda não é coletado, pois ainda existe uma Strong Reference para  Object, na sequencia, anulamos(null out) a variável strongRef(referência do tipo Strong), chamamos novamente o Garbage Collector e este é o resultado: null - mesmo com referência o Object foi coletado

```
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        // Declarando uma variável de referência fraca
        WeakReference<Object> weakRef = new WeakReference<>(new Object() {
            @Override
            public String toString() {//Customizando toString para fins didaticos
                return "I am a dummy object!";
            }
        });

        // Apontando mais uma referência para a String Test
        Object strongRef = weakRef.get();

        System.gc();//Nao utilizar este metodo em producao

        Thread.sleep(1000);

        //Aida ha uma String Reference para o Object, entao ele nao e coletado
        System.out.println(weakRef.get());

        //Null out stringRef
        strongRef = null;

        System.gc();

        Thread.sleep(2000);

        //Agora apenas restou a WeakReferencia, mesmo com ela, o Objeto ja esta elegivel
        System.out.println(weakRef.get());

    }
}
```

Resultado:

```
I am a dummy object!
null
```

**PhamtomReference**

PhamtomReferences são referências fantasmas, as quais não se é possível mais acessar o objeto, geralmente utilizadas como substitutos do método Object.finanlize. O método finalize foi criado para liberar recursos utilizado pelo Objeto, tais como conexões, arquivos abertos, etc. Não é recomendado utilizar-se dete método, ou seja, não é confiável sobreescreve-lo para estes fins, uma das razões é que este método permite a ressurreicão do objeto, além de afetar a performance do Garbage Collector, pois é ele que faz a invocacão, muitos finalizer == mais tempo para colecão de Objetos não atingiveis por referências.

*Phantom References to the rescue*

Referências Phantom(fantasmas) podem ser usadas para executar ações antes de um objeto seja coletado, em uma forma segura. No construtor de um `java.lang.ref.PhantomReference`, devemos especificar um fila -     `java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue` onde a referência phantom será enfileirada uma vez que o objeto referenciado torna-se "phantom reachable", alcançado apenas por uma referência fantasma. O que soa inicialmente um pouco confuso é que, embora uma referência fantasma continua a manter o objeto referenciado em um campo particular (ao contrário referências weak ou soft), o seu método GetReference() sempre retorna null. Isso é para que não seja possível fazer o objeto fortemente acessível novamente(ressurection).

```
import java.lang.ref.PhantomReference;
import java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        class Foo{
            private String foo = "abc";
            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "I am a foo";
            }
        }

        Foo f = new Foo();

        ReferenceQueue<Foo> q = new ReferenceQueue<Foo>();

        PhantomReference<Foo> phantomRef = new PhantomReference<Foo>(f, q);

        System.gc();

        System.out.println(f);

        f = null;

        System.gc();

        System.out.println("Esta na fial de referencias fantasmas? " + phantomRef.isEnqueued());

        PhantomReference<Foo> referenceFromQueue = null;

        while ( (referenceFromQueue =  (PhantomReference<Foo>) q.poll()) != null) {
            System.out.println("Sempre retorna null, certo? -> "+referenceFromQueue.get());
            referenceFromQueue.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Resultado:

```
 I am a foo
Esta na fial de referencias fantasmas? true
null
```

**Canonicalized Mapping e WeakHashMap**

Um mapeamento "canonicalized" permite manter-se uma instância do objeto em questão na memória e todos os outros objetos que necessitem deste, possam acessá-lo. Este é o momento onde Weaks References podem ajudar.

A resposta curta é que os objetos WeakReference pode ser usado para criar ponteiros para objetos em seu sistema enquanto ainda permitem que esses objetos a sejam coletados, uma vez estejam fora do escopo. Por exemplo:

```
 class Registrador {
     private Set objetosRegistrados = new HashSet();

     public void registrar(Object object) {
         objetosRegistrados.add( object );
     }
 }
```

Qualquer objeto registrado nunca será coletado pelo GC porque há uma referência a ele armazenada no Set objetosRegistrados. Então como resolvemos isto?

```
 class Registrador {
     private Set objetosRegistrados = new HashSet();

     public void registrar(Object object) {
         objetosRegistrados.add( new WeakReference(object)  );
     }
 }
```

**WeakHashMap**

A classe java.util.WeakHashMap usa referências fracas para fornecer apenas um mapeamento de Canonicalização. É possível adicionar pares de key-value(WeakHashMap implementa a interface Map) para uma instância WeakHashMap através do método put(), assim como você pode para uma instância de qualquer classe que implementa java.util.Map. Mas no interior, o WeakHashMap, os objectos principais são realizadas através de objectos de referência fracos que estão associados com uma fila de referência. Se o Garbage Collector determinar que uma das keys é fracamente acessível, ele irá limpar e enfileirar quaisquer objetos de referência fracos que se referem a essa key. A próxima vez que o WeakHashMap é acessado, ele vai pesquisar a fila de referência e extrair todos os objetos de referência fracos que o Garbage Collector colocou lá.

Comment: não tenho como não agradecer tão completa resposta/explicação!