# Como criar um WeakHashSet /WeakSet em Java

Tags: java, collection, referência, garbage-collector

O pacote java.lang.ref oferece classes que modelam tipos de referência em Java, tais como Reference, SoftReferece, WeakReference e PhantomReference.

> Ainda não conhece essas referências em Java? Consulte esta pergunta:
>   [Canonicalized Mapping e WeakReference](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/70031/canonicalized-mapping-e-weakreference/71101#71101)

Uma das classes do **Java SE** que utiliza WeakReference é a `java.util.WeakHashMap`, onde temos a `key` como referência fraca, ou seja, mesmo com referência a mesma é coletado no próximo ciclo do Garbase Collector(caso não haja nenhuma outra StrongReference).

> "...a WeakHashMap may behave as though an unknown thread is silently
>   removing entries."

Fonte Javadocs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html

Curiosamente, não temos uma implementacão de Set com essa semantica - WeakSet, pelo menos não na plataforma Java SE.

**Como então podemos obter uma instancia de WeakSet?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para criar um WeakHashSet, basta utilizar o seguinte método:

```
Set<Object> weakHashSet = Collections.newSetFromMap(
        new WeakHashMap<Object, Boolean>());
```

Interessantemente, a classe Collections, é uma classe com vários métodos incríveis, recomendo a todos que conhecam seus métodos, por exemplo, se quisermos uma versão sincronizada do WeakHashMap, mas fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
Collections.synchronizedMap(aWeakHashMap);
```

O que o método acima faz, é decorar o comportamento do WeakHashMap, sincronizando todos os seus métodos. Podemos usar este método para decorar qualquer outro Map

Fonte: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#newSetFromMap%28java.util.Map%29